# The "ASK QUESTION" animation is too long

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

The main site "ASK QUESTION" looks pleasing the first time you use it, but if you use the site a lot (like moderators, high rep users and aficionados do), it quickly becomes boring and "over the top".

Please use a much shorter and quieter animation.

Chrome, iMac
Safari, iMac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been shortened. the change will be in the next production build.